# is there a good way to find function define in header file in ace framework

Tags: ace

As a ace framework newer,  i always encounter some problem when using this framework.
I copy some example code from website and execute it in linux. however some error throw out because of no include correspond header file. for exmaple some error like this: error: ‘sleep’ is not a member of ‘ACE_OS’. 
so how can i found this function define in which header file

Comment: I just find a good website http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/5.8.3/html/libace-doc/index.html. Also i can find ACE_OS::sleep function define. but this website don't tell which header file include this define.

Comment: Here is a complete [function list](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/5.7.8/html/ace/functions_func.html).

Comment: hi Jonathon Reinhart. Also i can find ACE_OS::sleep function define. but this website don't tell which header file include this define

Comment: Most easiest is just to do a "grep sleep $ACE_ROOT/ace/OS*.h", that tells you the file where this method is defined. Other optin is to use the most recent doxygen tree at http://doxygen.theaceorb.nl/libace-doc/index.html

Comment: thx @Johnny Willemsen, you solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Most easiest is just to do a "grep sleep $ACE_ROOT/ace/OS*.h", that tells you the file where this method is defined. Other option is to use the most recent doxygen tree at http://doxygen.theaceorb.nl/libace-doc/index.html